# how to check if scheduler backups ran successfully

Tags: windows, delphi, scheduled-tasks, remote-execution

on each of our remote servers a scheduler task is created that calls an .exe program that shuts down the databases at 10:00:00 everyday (it create database backups)and start it up again at a specific time.now using the delphi application i need to now how can i check if the scheduler task backups were ran successfully(database shutdown and startup)...the ideas was to try and connect to the scheduler Task using delphi application and check the last run time(when didi it last execute or run the .exe using the DATETIME variable),status(is it running)..please assist i can connect to the server in delphi but i cant connect to the scheduler task in the server.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I'm doing for my own automated backups: The application that does the actual backup updates a DATETIME column in the database with the last successful backup date and time. From the usual client application I can read the given DATETIME column and issue warnings if backups are getting old.

Advantages: Nothing complicated about it (KISS!), no need to figure out API's to read the scheduler, no need to figure out "exit codes" for when the backup started but wasn't successful, works even if backups are being made from multiple locations.